# Visualizer onFftDataCapture - Does the byte[] index represent frequency?

Tags: android, audio, byte, visualizer

I'm having understanding the Android Visualizer's

```
onFftDataCapture((Visualizer visualizer, 
            byte[] fft, 
            int samplingRate)
```

How do I know which frequency is represented by which `byte` in `fft`?

For example, would the index be a representation of frequency? Like `index = frequency`?

For index 0, frequency is 0 Hz, index 1 is 1 Hz, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FFT produces complex numbers, where each number reflects frequency domain information about a bucket containing a continuous range frequencies. The usual approach for interpreting FFT data is as follows:

- first determine the frequency bucket size by dividing the length of the FFT table by the sampling rate, let's call it `bucketSize`;
- then each bucket with index `i` (assuming it's 0-based) contains information about frequencies in the range from `i * bucketSize` to `(i + 1) * bucketSize` Hz;
- for real-valued signals, the values of the second half of the FFT table (for buckets of frequencies above `samplingRate / 2`) will be just a mirror of the first half, so they are usually discarded;
- also, for the first (index `0`) and for the last (index `samplingRate / 2`) buckets, the value of the FFT table will be real as well (assuming real-valued signal);
- to find the magnitude (signal level) for the frequencies in the bucket, one needs to take the complex value from the FFT table for this bucket, say it's `a + ib`, and calculate `sqrt(a*a + b*b)`.

Now back to the results of `onFftDataCapture`. Here the `fft` array contains complex numbers as consecutive pairs of bytes, except for the first two elements, so `fft[2]` and `fft[3]` comprise the complex number for the first bucket, `fft[4]` and `fft[5]` -- for the second, and so on. Whereas `fft[0]` is the FFT value (real) for the 0-th frequency (DC), and `fft[1]` is for the last frequency.

Because, as I've mentioned, for real-valued signals the second part of the FFT table doesn't bring any benefit, it's **not** provided in the `fft` array. But since each FFT bucket takes two array cells, the bucket size in Hz will still be calculated as `fft.length / samplingRate`. Note that `fft.length` is actually the capture size set by `setCaptureSize` method of the Visualizer.

The magnitude of the bucket of frequencies can be easily calculated using `Math.hypot` function, e.g. for the first bucket it's `Math.hypot(fft[2], fft[3])`. For the DC bucket it's simply `Math.abs(fft[0])`, and for last frequency bucket it's `Math.abs(fft[1])`.

Comment: Super helpful! Do you have any additional sources for reference or is this just stuff you've learned over time?

Comment: @Epicality I'm not sure if you are asking about the FFT itself, or this function. I've learned about the latter mostly from its source code. In fact, I could be wrong about the contents of fft[1]—according to the docs on Visualizer.getFft function ( https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Visualizer.html#getFft(byte[]) ), the element fft[1] contains the real part of the last bucket (SR / 2). I will check that. If you want to know more about Fourier transform, there is a whole book on it: https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/st/

Comment: Thanks, man! I'm trying to add a color-based music visualizer to my navigation customization app. I appreciate the help here.

Comment: @MikhailNaganov are you sure that frequency bucket size equals to fft[].lenght / sampling rate?
In this comment I can see it'st samplingRate / fft[].length 
https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/26927/what-is-a-frequency-bin#comment96383_26980